# Is there a method for reading characters from an instance of subprocess.Popen when the process it called has not yet issued a newline?

Tags: python, newline, subprocess, popen

I am attempting to wrap a program that is routinely used at work.  When called with an insufficient number of arguments, or with a misspelled argument, the program issues a prompt to the user, asking for the needed input.  As a consequence, when calling the routine with subprocess.Popen, the routine never sends any information to stdout or stderr when wrong parameters are passed.  subprocess.Popen.communicate() and subprocess.Popen.read(1) both wait for a newline character before any information becomes available.

Is there any way to retrieve information from subprocess.Popen.stdout before the newline character is issued?  If not, is there any method that can be used to determine whether the subprocess is waiting for input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After asking around quite a bit, someone pointed me to the solution.  Use pexpect.spawn and pexpect.expect.  For example:

Bash "script" in a file titled prompt.sh to emulate the problem - read cannot be called directly from pexpect.spawn.
    #!/bin/bash

```
read -p "This is a prompt: "
```

This will hang when called by subprocess.Popen.  It can be handled by pexpect.spawn, though:

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn('./prompt.sh')
child.expect(search)
>>> 0
print child.after #Prints the matched text
>>> 'This is a prompt: '
```

A list, compiled regex, or list of compiled regex can also be used in place of the string in pexpect.expect to deal with differing prompts.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to try: use the `bufsize` argument to [Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), and set it to `0`:

```
subprocess.Popen(args, bufsize=0, ...)
```

Unfortunately, whether or not this works also depends upon how the *subprocess* flushes its output, and I presume you don't have much control over that.

On some platforms, when data written to `stdout` is flushed will actually *change* depending on whether the underlying I/O library detects an interactive terminal or a pipe. So while you might think the data is there waiting to be read — because that's how it works in a terminal window — it might actually be line buffered when you're running the same program as a subprocess from another within Python.

**Added:** I just realised that `bufsize=0` is the default anyway. Nuts.

Comment: Actually, bufsize=0 is the default for subprocess.Popen.  Thanks for the try, though!

Comment: @Vorticity - heh, yeah, I saw that after posting :/